# referencing data within the groups of a list in F#

Tags: list, f#, grouping

I performed my first query with a grouping function using the following code:

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics

let newData = query { for x in dc.MyData do
                      where (x.ID = "number of type string")
                      groupBy x.Code into g
                      let average = query { for x in g do
                                            averageBy x.Billed_Amt }
                      select (g, average) }
                      |> Seq.toList

System.Console.WriteLine(newData)
```

I am now wanting to calculate the standard deviation of the billed amounts in each group. However, when I try to reference the column, 'Billed_Amt,' like so

```
let sd = newData.Billed_Amt.StandardDeviation()
```

I receive the following error: "constructor or member 'Billed_Amt' is not defined."

I also tried newData.g.Billed_Amt.StandardDeviation(), in case I needed to reference the groups first, but I got the same error message referring to 'g'.

How do I overcome this?

I will say that I notice that the 'list' I created with the query claims to have 63 items. These would be the different group keys, not the rows of data themselves.

I feel like the research I have done online to solve this problem has just sent me in circles. Most of the resources online do not dumb it down enough for newbies like me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `List.head newData` to get the first element of the list, then go from there?

Comment: Simple suggestion: check the types and look them up to see what they mean and their available members. `IGrouping` is a good place to start.